# How to Pass " double quotes through Scenario outline example

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd

How to pass double quotes through Cucumber Scenario Outline Example, When I type double quote in Example, Scenario step will be inactive. In below Scenario `username"1` I am not able to pass. Anybody suggest how to pass double quote through Scenario Outline, Thanks.

```
 Scenario Outline:Login detail
        And I enter "<username>" and "<password>"
        Example:
        | username  | password  | 
        | username"1 | password1 | 
        | username2 | password2 |
```

Comment: have you tried escaping double quotes using \ like `username\"1` ?

Comment: @SampatBadhe: I tried this but not worked

Comment: I have tried similar use case using 'Examples' instead of Example. It worked as expected. Scenario Outline: Name
Given Test with "<ex1>"
Examples:
|ex1|
|thot\"va|

Comment: Which language, which Cucumber version?

Comment: @Sreenivasulu, I have used Examples only and tried |username\"1| but not worked, related to this Example step is active, if used like this. Even I tried ||username\"1| here 2 pipeline considering separate column in Examples

Comment: @vishwa In which language have you tried? I tried with cucumber-js using Typescript..

Comment: @Sreenivasulu: Cucumber -Java In IntelliJ I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try escaping the double quotes using back slash (i.e. ). Please check the following gif which shows how it is done using NoCodeBDD. However, I believe, the same should work in other script based tools like Cucumber.

https://nocodebdd.live/examples-with-double-quotes

Disclaimer: I created this product to speed up automation of BDDs without having to write any code. I would love to get some feedback on the product from the community. You can download a free version from https://www.nocodedd.com/download

Comment: Thank you all for your help, It worked me for adding regular expression (.*) in step defination.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass it like below :
username"1

Comment: @Rababa: Please give more detail, how to pass double quotation in Scenario Examples

Comment: @vishwa please share the step definition